# getting issue insert data into database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
/*This is my controller: */

public function register()
    {
        //$this -> output -> enable_profiler( TRUE );
        $this -> load -> library( 'form_validation' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');  
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'staff', 'Staff Number', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[15]' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[15]' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[15]' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'middle', 'Middle Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[15]' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'username', 'User Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[15]' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[10]' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'gender', 'Gender', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'dob', 'DOB', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'status', 'Status', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'role', 'Role', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'street', 'Street', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'area', 'Area', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'city', 'City', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'state', 'State', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'zip', 'Code', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'mobile', 'Mobile', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'home', 'Home', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'email', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'image', 'Image', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'degree', 'Qualification', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'college', 'University', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'exp', 'Experience', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'hire', 'Hire', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'term', 'Term', 'required' );
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'ret', 'Retireement', 'required' );

        //Setting custom error messages
        $this -> form_validation -> set_message( 'min_length', 'Minimum length for %s is %s characters');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_message( 'max_length', 'Maximum length for %s is %s characters');

        if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE )
        {

            $this->view();

        }
        else
        {
            $this->user_model->add_userdetails(); 

        }

    }
```

/* This is my model:
    This model used to insert data into database. my issue doesn't store data into database.*/

```
public function add_userdetails()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $insert_data=array(
    'staff_number'=>$this->input->post('staff'),
    'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name'=>$this->input->post('last_name'),
    'middle_name'=>$this->input->post('middle'),
    'user_name'=>$this->input->post('username'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
    //'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password'))
    'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
    'date_oF_birth'=>$this->input->post('dob'),
    'status'=>$this->input->post('status'),
    'gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
    'role'=>$this->input->post('role'),
    'street'=>$this->input->post('street'),
    'area'=>$this->input->post('area'),
    'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),
    'state'=>$this->input->post('state'),
    'zip_code'=>$this->input->post('zip'),
    'mobile_number'=>$this->input->post('mobile'),
    'home_number'=>$this->input->post('home'),
    'other_phone_number'=>$this->input->post('other'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
    'profile_image_path'=>$image_data['image'],
    'path' => $image_data['file_path'],
    'thumb_path'=> $image_data['file_path'] . 'thumbs/'. $image_data['file_name'],
    'spousename'=>$this->input->post('spouse'),
    'more_info'=>$this->input->post('more'),
    'qualification'=>$this->input->post('degree'),
    'university'=>$this->input->post('college'),
    'experience'=>$this->input->post('exp'),
    'subject_matter_expert'=>$this->input->post('sub'),
    'additional_curricular_activities'=>$this->input->post('add_act'),
    'rewards_achievements'=>$this->input->post('achieve'),
    'memberships'=>$this->input->post('member'),
    'address_others'=>$this->input->post('other'),
    'date_of_hire'=>$this->input->post('hire'),
    'date_of_termination'=>$this->input->post('term'),
    'date_of_retriement'=>$this->input->post('ret'),

    );


    $this->db->insert('staff',$insert_data);  //insert data into database
//print_r($insert_data);exit;   

}
```

Comment: put echo $this->db->last_query();die;after $this->db->insert('staff',$insert_data); and run the query into your database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change this line `$this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE` to `$this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE`
2. Inside the model function `add_userdetails()` write `echo $this->db->last_query();die;` just after this line `$this->db->insert('staff',$insert_data);` and let me know.